# jQuery drag/drop unbinds child links

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, unbind

I want a draggable div to include a clickable link.
Everything works fine until i drag and drop the div.
The link inside seems to unbind after drag/drop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to try and recreate it somehow as the following example of what you're describing works fine:

http://jsbin.com/ilali4/edit